# How can I draw over a GridPane of Rectangles with an Image? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, image, user-interface, javafx, chess

So I am trying to display a chessboard in Java. So far, I can correctly draw and color a bunch of rectangles and have the window and rectangles resize properly. However, now i want to add an image of a chess piece on top of those rectangles, and I am not sure how to proceed.

I create an imageview of a png for a chess piece, but when I try adding it to the gridpane like i did the rectangles, it gives me a duplicate child error.

Here is the code that works so far

```
package test3;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
/**
 *

 */
public class Test3 extends Application {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    final int size = 8;
    ImageView pawn = new ImageView("file:pawn.png");
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
                Color color;
                if ((row + col) % 2 == 0) { 
                    color = Color.CHOCOLATE;
                }
                else {
                    color = Color.ANTIQUEWHITE;
                }
                square.setFill(color);
                
                root.add(square, col, row);
                square.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(size));
                square.heightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(size));
                
            }
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

What would be the best way to create an imageview of a chess piece and draw it on top of the rectangles, like how chess pieces are on a board? I already have a file, say pawn.png, i can make an imageview of it, but any time i try to add the image view to the gridpane where i drew rectangles, it gives errors. I am not sure what to do. I tried having a second gridpane where i only add the images, but that also gives duplicate child errors.

Comment: Use `Pane`s (or some suitable subclass) instead of the rectangles, and add image views to them.

Comment: How would i go about having the background rectangle then?

Comment: Use the `Pane`s *instead* of the rectangles.

Comment: hm, I see. However, it seems trying to set the Color of a pane is a bit more complicated, and examples I find online dont seem to work properly, doing things like pane.setbackground(new backgroundfill()), but the IDE just throws out errors with that

Comment: That won’t even compile. Just read the Java docs. You can use `setStyle(…)` too, or set a style class or pseudoclass and use an external CSS file (that is probably the preferred approach).

Comment: hm, I see, seems a lot more complicated than the rectangles, but it will have the value of adding image panes. However, this also means my resizing window solution doesnt work either. And doing a quick test trying setStyle, it seems like it only draws one tiny tiny tiny tiny little box in the corner, that looks like a mini checkerboard in itself, but mega tiny. Is it possible to still use the rectangle idea, but have like layered gridpanes or something, with a rectangle on one 'layer' and the imageview on another?

Comment: Yes, of course; you could use `StackPane`s in each cell and place the rectangle and image view in the stack pane. But that seems to add additional complexity to the scene graph. If the CSS solution isn’t working, you’re doing something wrong.

Comment: “it gives me a duplicate child error” -> ImageView is a node.  A node can only be attached to one position in the Scene graph at a time.  However, multiple ImageViews can be associated with a single image.  That is what you want.  So for chess you will have a single white pawn image, but 8 InageViews, one for each white pawn on the board. See the info on nodes in scenes before the example in the [scene package javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/package-summary.html).

Comment: i managed to fix the tiny square issue, turns out i was dumb and had them set to be 1px squares :p . But is there a CSS string that can make it resizable based on window size like I had my rectangles? I know like nothing about CSS

Comment: Alternately, A [fixed size board based on rectangles in a pane](https://javabook.bloomu.edu/code-html/Chapter6/Checkerboard.html), to overlay put each rectangle in a StackPane before adding to the scene then you can put your pieces in the appropriate stack pane to overlay the rectangle for the square.  Or you could just add the pieces to the pane after creating the background.  JavaFX works on the painters algorithm (Google it) so stuff added to the parent pane last will paint over stuff added first.

Comment: [resizable styled grid](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2030464), it is a grid of colors in a chooser so is more complex than a checkerboard.  The addition functionality of the example combined with the additional styling and resizing capability contributes to the extra complexity over the fixed size implementation, so might just confuse you rather than clarify things.

Answer (score 5):

(Some of my points might have already addressed in comments)

The first thing you need to fix is to create separate ImageView nodes for each square, as you cannot duplicate the nodes in scenegraph.

Irrespective of Rectangle or StackPane as your square, you can fix the problem.

**Using Rectangle:**

If you prefer to use Rectangle, you can just include the ImageView node in the same grid location of Rectangle and adjust the width/height of the ImageView node w.r.t the Rectangle.

```
ImageView pawn = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("pawn.png").toExternalForm());
root.add(pawn, col, row);
pawn.fitWidthProperty().bind(square.widthProperty().subtract(2));
pawn.fitHeightProperty().bind(square.heightProperty().subtract(2));
```

**Using StackPane:**

The approach is pretty much same as using Rectangle, but you will place the ImageView node in the StackPane instead of GridPane. The added advantage of using StackPane is that the ImageView will be automatically centered to your square. You can also include an optional code to resize the image to fit to the square.

```
Background dark = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CHOCOLATE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
Background light = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        ImageView pawn = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("pawn.png").toExternalForm());
        StackPane square = new StackPane(pawn);
        square.setBackground((row + col) % 2 == 0?dark:light);
        root.add(square, col, row);
        square.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(size));
        square.prefHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(size));

        // Comment the below two lines if you don't want the images to resize.
        pawn.fitWidthProperty().bind(square.widthProperty().subtract(2));
        pawn.fitHeightProperty().bind(square.heightProperty().subtract(2));
    }
}
```

Either of the above two approaches produces the same result as below gif. The working demo is below:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChessBoardDemo extends Application {
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    final int size = 8;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        yourApproach();
        // usingPane(); 
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.setTitle("ChessBoard");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void usingPane() {
        Background dark = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.CHOCOLATE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
        Background light = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ANTIQUEWHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY));
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                ImageView pawn = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("pawn.png").toExternalForm());
                StackPane square = new StackPane(pawn);
                square.setBackground((row + col) % 2 == 0 ? dark : light);
                root.add(square, col, row);
                square.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(size));
                square.prefHeightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(size));

                // Comment the below two lines if you don't want the images to resize.
                pawn.fitWidthProperty().bind(square.widthProperty().subtract(2));
                pawn.fitHeightProperty().bind(square.heightProperty().subtract(2));
            }
        }
    }

    private void yourApproach() {
        for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
                Rectangle square = new Rectangle();
                square.setFill((row + col) % 2 == 0 ? Color.CHOCOLATE : Color.ANTIQUEWHITE);

                root.add(square, col, row);
                square.widthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().divide(size));
                square.heightProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().divide(size));

                ImageView pawn = new ImageView(getClass().getResource("pawn.png").toExternalForm());
                root.add(pawn, col, row);
                pawn.fitWidthProperty().bind(square.widthProperty().subtract(2));
                pawn.fitHeightProperty().bind(square.heightProperty().subtract(2));
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]